# Microsoft Word - Switch to Reading layout

Tags: microsoft-word, boot, automation

Is there a way to configure Microsoft Word (2003 if possible) to automatically switch to [Reading Layout](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP030917351033.aspx) when opening any document? Perhaps select the "Multiple page" option as well?

Yes, I can press Alt+R or press the button to turn it on, but I want to do it automatically.

EDITED:

Thanks to WireGuy I found the answer - add a new VBA method in normal.dot file:

```
Sub AutoOpen()
Options.AllowReadingMode = True
ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about writing an AutoOpen macro, and storing it in Normal.dot
<strike>Looks like it would be Options.AllowReadingMode = True</strike>

ActiveWindow.View.ReadingLayout = True

Comment: According to this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa212547%28office.11%29.aspx it looks like AllowReadingMode Property will only enable/disable the Reading Layout feature but it will not activate it..

Comment: Property Options.AllowReadingMode will only tick/untick the corresponding box in the Options menu; however any documents still open in "Print Layout"